# multiple google charts with separate options

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

I'm starting out with google charts (gauges)

i need to put multiple gauges on the same page, each with a different max value (which is set in options)

but what it seems is that the options is somehow global for all charts

they all become 0 to 1

here's my code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', { 'packages': ['gauge'] });
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
        $.getJSON("Dashboard/GaugeData", function (jsn) {
            var dGauges = $('#gauges');
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
            data.addColumn('string', 'Label');
            data.addColumn('number', 'Value');
            $.each(jsn, function (i, item) {
                data.addRow([item.Label, item.Pending]);
                var chart = new google.visualization.Gauge(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
                chart.draw(data, {
                    width: 400, height: 400,
                    redFrom: 90, redTo: 100,
                    yellowFrom: 75, yellowTo: 90,
                    minorTicks: 5, max: item.Max
                });
            });
        });
    } setInterval(function () {
        drawChart();
    }, 10000);
</script>
```

please note that i cannot prepare a new div for each chart, since the amount of charts is dynamic (from json)

i believe i could create the divs dynamically and then check before each refresh if i need to add the div or remove etc... but i'm hoping there's a better way

Comment: for separate options, must have separate charts, for separate charts, must have separate divs -- you could use the value of the `'Label'` column as `id` -- when ajax loads, see if div exists, otherwise create...

Comment: thanks, that's actually what i mentioned at the end of my post... i just thought there might be a cleaner way...